# Prevent a StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer to move the selected item automatically to the top

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I have a structure in WPF as follows:

```
 <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
     <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="790" Margin="13,9,10,0" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
          <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" Height="770" Width="650" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
     </ScrollViewer>
 </Grid>
```

My program puts several `UserControl`s inside the `StackPanel`. When I select one of the elements of the `UserControl` that is not on the top of the `ScrollViewer`, it automatically moves to the top.

Is there a way to prevent this and leave it in place and only allow the user to scroll up and down whenever he/she wants to?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I changed the title of your question. Please refer to [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to get informed whether you should use any tags in the question title.